# Add 'last' class to second post in featured post loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

Hi there I'm using the following query to pull in two featured posts onto the home page of a site I'm building. How do I add a last class to the second post it drops onto the page?

```
                <h3>Case Studies</h3>
            <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=casestudy&posts_per_page=2');
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="half">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <p class="home-news-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could do it involving incrementing and checking a counter variable. I prefer to use the built-in member vars present in the main and every custom `WP_Query`.

This will give you the index of the current post in the loop:

```
$my_query->current_post
```

Just remember that it's zero indexed, meaning the first post is 0, second is 1, etc..

and this will give you the number of posts returned from your query:

```
$my_query->post_count
```

so we just combine those in an `if` statement to check if it's the last post in the loop. Remember to add 1 to current post here because it starts at zero:

```
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

    $class = 'half';
    if( ( $my_query->current_post + 1 ) == $my_query->post_count ){
        $class .= ' last';
    }

    echo '<div class="' . $class . '">';
    // rest of your markup, etc..

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `$my_query->current_post` and you can easily determine which post you are on. I used that to set the post class and then used the [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) function to insert that class and all of the defaults.

```
<h3>Case Studies</h3>
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=2');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; 
    $new_class = (1 === $my_query->current_post) ? 'half' : '' ?>
    <div <?php post_class($new_class); ?>>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
      <p class="home-news-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
```

Note that `*->current_post` starts indexing at `0` so `1` is the second post.